# Javascript XML Http Request show progress of download in Chrome bottom bar?

Tags: javascript, xml, http

I'm facing the problem that my progress of the file I download doesnt get shown in the chrome bottom download bar.

My file only shows up when the download already is finished like 54mb/54mb. 
[image: download picture]

How can I show the progress of the download in the download bar like other files also do? 0mb/54mb ... 10mb/54mb and so on.

This is my javascript code:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = 'blob';
          xhr.onload = function() {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
            a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
            a.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
          };
          xhr.open('GET', url);
          xhr.send();
```

Comment: which part attempts to show the progress? generally,  XHR requests don't show progress in the status bar, that would be annoying

Comment: what you mean? as shown in the image the file does only show up when the download is finished. as you can see here "55,2MB/55,2MB" ... But I want it to show from the beginning when "0MB/55,2MB" until its finished.

Comment: I guess your file is missing or file download handler is missing `Content-Length` header.

Comment: it only shows up because you are triggering a file save, that's what is showing ... and of course, that only happens once the XHR request completes ... what you'll want to do is create your progress indication using other means ... modern browsers have `<progress>` tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Comment: @AdamAzad my file isnt missing. Its downloading fine. But only in background. And when its finished it does show up like in the picture. But I want that it shows up the whole download. In example 0MB/52MB until 52MB/52MB and the download is finished

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah ok I understand that. So with the <progress> tags it will show the download progress in the download bar of google chrome?

Comment: to summarise: the chrome bottom download bar is for showing downloading/downloaded files, an XHR is not a download as such, despite it downloading data

Comment: no, the `<progress>` tag is something you'll need to add to the web page - you can not add to the chrome download bar as far as I can tell

Comment: Ah okey. Do you know something else than XHR where I can download files from Server with Javascript? Because its really IMPORTANT for me that it does show in the download bar.